# How to make action get triggered as long as key is held in Unity new input system

Tags: unity, c#, input

I'm using unity new input system for a local multiplayer game.
My PlayerInput sends messages to my CharacterInputListener on every character object, one of such messages is OnDefend().

[image]

I want defendRequest to be true as long as the button bound to the action is being held and false otherwise.

[image]

I am trying to use the hold interaction but it returns false the frame after the button is held for 0.01 seconds. How can I achieve the behaviour I want?